# Not being able to update ubuntu on Azure VM's

Tags: azure, ubuntu-18.04, azure-virtual-machine, public-key, apt-get

**Problem:**

I tried to create VM's and then update it to install the azure-cli but am facing this NO_PUBKEY error.

```
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

---

**My Ubuntu Configuration:**

NAME="Ubuntu"

VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"

---

**Steps to recreate:**

1. Create a Azure VM

   - Image: [image]
   - Size: [image]
   - And the rest as the default configurations
2. `curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash` &
3. `sudo apt-get update`

---

**What other things I did to solve this problem:**

1. Created another VM with same configuration and got the same problem. So I think that the problem was not only to that particular VM

---

Comment: Try the manual steps here https://www.devopshint.com/how-to-install-azure-cli-on-ubuntu/?

Comment: Tried it @NancyXiong. getting same errors at 'sudo apt-get update'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error message, you could add missing keys by executing the following command for each key from the log file:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

**Note**: the actual key server name and the key mentioned in the error message should be used in the command above.

After adding the missing keys, you could try to install the azure-cli again.

For more information, you could refer to [this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006278554-Plesk-update-fails-GPG-error-The-following-signatures-couldn-t-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available-NO-PUBKEY).

Comment: Tried this as well. Still shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much research I found out that the problem existed only on certain Nvidia Images and not on the barebone Linux images. So I figured that there must be something wrong with the trusted key itself. So, these are the steps that I did in order to fix the issue.

---

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
sudo apt-get update
curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
```

---

Now you will be able to update the instance

---

Resources:
[1] http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=130558

---